# How to shrink a table created with tabularx?

Tags: tables, graphics, tabularx

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.5}{
\begin{tabularx}{r|lll}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 1}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 2}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 3} \\ \cline{2-4}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3
\end{tabularx}}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Using `tabular` instead of `tabularx` works just fine. Using `tabularx` generates

```
 Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> error.
```

Comment: You have to set the desired table width in the first argument and to use at least one `X` column. Eg: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|lll}`

Comment: the error is unrelated to scaling, but only apply scaling to tables as a last resort (and even then don't do it) you would not justify a paragraph of text by scaling the font to an arbitrary size just to make it fit, why do that to a table?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately, I have to scale. The table width overflows the right margin by 80pts and I don't know any other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: @esdd Setting one of the columns to X gives me weird result like this in the original file http://imgur.com/a/Y7pfx (first row)

Comment: @SamidhT if you use tabularx and specify it as textwidth the table will be textwidth wide and not overflow, you _never_ need to scale. If you need smaller fonts you can use `\small` or `\footnotesize`

Comment: if you do not use an `X` column then definitely do not use `tabularx`

Comment: What's the purpose of the `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` "wrappers" for cells in columns of type `l`?

Comment: The "Missing number, treated as zero." message is issued because you've failed to provide one of the two required arguments of the `tabularx` environment: The missing argument is the *intended width* (frequently, but not aways, `\textwidth`). Writing `\begin{tabularx}{r|lll}` is a mistake; it should be something like `\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{r|XXX}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sure if this is an issue but when I use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|c|}` it does overflow.

Comment: how many times do we have to say? using `tabularx` with no `X` column is just wrong, any output you get at all is totally accidental in that case,

Answer (score 2):

Using `tabularx` without at least one `X` column does not make sense. Aditionally `tabularx` takes two manadantory arguments. In the first one you have to set the desired width of the table. If there is no width in the first argument, you get the error message which is mentioned in your question.

From your comments it seems that you do not want to use `tabularx`.

If you really want to scale your table to eg. `\linewidth`, you can use `\resizebox`. But it is not recommended at all to scale a table ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering% used instead the environment center
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{r|lll}
      \multicolumn{1}{r}{}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 1}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 2}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 3} \\ \cline{2-4}
      Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
      Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason I use tabularx is that I have a table with number of rows spanning multiple pages. tabular tries to fit all of them in a single page whereas tabularx nicely puts them onto multiple pages. I am considering splitting the table up into multiple tabular tables so I can then use resizebox.

Comment: @SamidhT no `tabularx` as defined by the `tabularx` package you loaded in your question never breaks over a page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisleYes I believe my MWE wasn't an accurate representation of my issue. If I remove the encompassing `\begin{table}` it does break over pages.

Comment: Then you are probably loading package `ltablex`.  Note that commands like `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` results in boxes without page breaks.

Comment: @SamidhT no with the packages you loaded `tabularx` would never break over a page, I wrote the thing, I know what it does, see esdd's comment above.

Comment: @esdd I think thats the issue. I am using resizebox over page breaks so that shouldn't work.